# Getting an image's original width and height in jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, preloading

I need to get the original width and height of an image given a specific source. My current method is:

```
img.tag = "<img style='display:none;' src='" + img.src + "' />";
img.Owidth = 0;
img.Oheight = 0;

$(img.tag).load(function() {
    img.Owidth = $(this).width();
    img.Oheight = $(this).height();
}).appendTo(img.parent());
```

With `Owidth` and `Oheight` being the original dimensions of the loaded image. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this given that:

- The image could either already be loaded, but displayed at a different size than its original size.
- The image has not yet been loaded at all

Comment: I'm doing something very similar and it's working pretty good for me. I'm working on a viewer that could show images at original size, fit width, fit all, etc., so it's helpful to know the original size, and I'm lazy loading images. Is your current code working for you and you're just wondering about a better way to do it?

Comment: This code is working fine for me, MrOBrian and yeah, I just want to see if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: This seems a double of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395931/how-do-i-get-actual-image-width-and-height-using-jquery) - though the accepted answer here seems the best of them all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Cross-Browser:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ayhLB/38/)***

```
$("<img/>").load(function(){
    var width  = this.width,
        height = this.height; 
    alert( 'W='+ width +' H='+ height);
}).attr("src", "image.jpg");
```

---

### HTMLImageElement properties / HTML5 compliant browsers

If you want to investigate about all the HTMLImageElement **properties**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement
Many of those properties are available already in modern, **HTML5 compliant browsers**, and accessible using jQuery's [`.prop()` metod](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ayhLB/39/)***

```
var $img = $("#myImage");

console.log(
    $img.prop("naturalWidth") +'\n'+  // Width  (Natural)
    $img.prop("naturalHeight") +'\n'+ // Height (Natural)
    $img.prop("width") +'\n'+         // Width  (Rendered)
    $img.prop("height") +'\n'+        // Height (Rendered)
    $img.prop("x") +'\n'+             // X offset
    $img.prop("y")                    // Y offset ... 
);
```

Comment: I think that it's better to append the image to the DOM at the end of the load() method. Otherwise I don't get the correct size (tested in Firefox).

Comment: @Simon tested in FF works. As you can see, no matter where you use appendTo (you can also remove `.appendTo(` from the script above) the image is loaded into that in-memory HTML image element. So I don't get your comment.

Comment: The problem appears if the image size is modified in CSS. Here is a fiddle that illustrates the problem (and the solution): http://jsfiddle.net/tsjg7/1/

Comment: That's exactly my point. If you want the original image size do not append it to the dom before the load function if over, or you'll get a wrong size if css rules are applied to the image. I think that the fiddle illustrate it well.

Comment: This is good, but one suggestion,  the load definition should come before setting the src. You are creating a race condition where the image might be loaded before the load function is defined.

Comment: @JeffRyan exactly. Crystal eyes, good suggestion. *Edited.* :)

Answer (score 21):

For Chrome and Firefox (and hopefully IE soon), you can use...

```
var width = $('img').prop('naturalWidth');
var height = $('img').prop('naturalHeight');
```

Comment: you are hero :)

Comment: How would one display these values from the code you have posted next to the image, or somewhere on the image itself?