# Zoom on a picture on resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm developing a website where I have to display a picture (not a problem).
But, I have to display it as this link: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

So, On resizing, I have to zoom on the picture to never scale it.
Does some on know how to do it?

Here is what I have:

html:

```
<div id="container_images">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/desktop/myimage.jpg" alt="An awesome image"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container_images{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container_images li{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: -30;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:1;
}

#container_images li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please don't expect users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please include a working example as part of your question.

Comment: Editing my post, sorry

Comment: Are you talking about resizing with ctrl+/-?

Comment: Yes, I need to center the picture and zoom in (ctrl+) when I'm increasing the width of the window

Comment: what does this have to do with php

Comment: Your question states: "I have to zoom on the picture to never scale it", but in the comments you've written: "I need to center the picture and zoom in". Do you want to zoom in or not? What does it have to do with resizing?

Comment: using (ctrl+/-) is not going to work because you can't remove the default functionality of browsers to zoom in/out on a page using their own methodology.

Comment: What I would like to do is to center a picture into a div and fill up the div completely with my image. But, I want to keep the proportion of the image this is why I need to zoom like the link exemple.

Comment: I found this: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you don't need the browser's inbuilt zooming (ctrl+), you just want to make the picture fill in the whole window of the browser when the window is resized.

You will need 2 things for that.

First, you need some javascript to execute on window resize event, then you will need some simple maths to calculate the center of the picture taking into account the new window size and set left/top margin of the picture to new values.

You can easily do that with [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    var pic = $('#container_images img');
    var pic_width = pic.width(), pic_height = pic.height();

    $(pic).css('margin-left': (w - pic_width)/2).css('margin-top': (h - pic_height)/2);
});
```

One thing to remember is that if your picture's width/height is already changed from its original size, you will get that new size from width() and height() functions.

So you either should make sure the original is not touched, or use one of the solution out there for grabbing the original picture size (e.g. [How do I get actual image width and height using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395931/how-do-i-get-actual-image-width-and-height-using-jquery)).

Also the above snippet is to just get you started, you should grab the picture and its parameters in some init function and only recalculate/modify css on resize event.