# Is there a way to get an image's width which's auto in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This problem has been bordering me since day one:

if i got an image and I resize it with css:

```
.img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

and let's say I am gonna get the height of this image, by using

```
var imgH = $('.img').height();
```

imgH will be returned in 0, but I wanna get the height which's the size that's been processed by the css, how to tackle?

Thanks!

---

Sorry guys you are right, I tried the examples and tested it on my client's project, they are turned out all working, and I tried to reproduce the value 0 error but I fail to. I kinda lost in this while I still remember I trapped in this for a few times before. Anyway, problem solved, Thanks to @SrinivasR!:)

Comment: just do `$('.img').height()`

Comment: I tried this, and the call to `.height()` worked fine; although it returns `0` if the image element has been created but not inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Yeah.check my answer here.

Comment: Please refer below URL:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395931/how-do-i-get-actual-image-width-and-height-using-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").load(function() {
        alert($(this).height());
        alert($(this).width());
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LECWe/35/)**

Comment: I updated now.I am just directly accessing image tag rather than class