# Find unknown image dimension in jQuery and PrototypeJS

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, dimension

[image: bar1]

I want to find out dimension of this image in px.

In jQuery

```
var h = $("img").height();
var w = $("img").width();
alert(h +"px", w +"px");
```

In PrototypeJS

```
var h = $('img').getHeight();
var w = $('img').getWidth();
alert(h);
alert(w);
```

using this two I get dimensions as 20px and 1350px for every image with their original different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get actual size of the image, not the size that it was rendered to web browser?
If that's the case, these code might help you:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = $("#myimg").attr('src');
```

Reference here: [How do I get actual image width and height using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395931/how-do-i-get-actual-image-width-and-height-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$('img')` will target every image in your DOM, the `20px` and `1350px` is the dimension of your first image. You need to use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) in this case:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var w = $(this).width(),
            h = $(this).height();
        alert(h +"px " + w +"px");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bCSpL/1/)

But I'd suggest you giving a class to your images instead of just selecting pure `<img>` tag:

```
<img class="image" />
```

Then you can do:

```
$(".image").click(function() {
    var w = $(this).width(),
        h = $(this).height();
    alert(h +"px " + w +"px");
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCSpL/)**