# AngularJS - Image "onload" event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, onload, jqlite

I've been searching for an answer to simple but not trivial question: What is a right way to catch image' `onload` event in Angular only with jqLite? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018685/display-image-in-its-actual-size-in-angular-js) , but I want some solution with directives.
So as I said, this is not accepted for me:

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    // ...
    img.onload = function () {
        // ...
    }
```

because it is in controller, not in directive.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's a re-usable directive in the style of angular's inbuilt event handling directives:

```
angular.module('sbLoad', [])

  .directive('sbLoad', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.sbLoad);
        elem.on('load', function (event) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(scope, { $event: event });
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

When the img load event is fired the expression in the sb-load attribute is evaluated in the current scope along with the load event, passed in as $event. Here's how to use it:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img sb-load="onImgLoad($event)">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    // ...
    $scope.onImgLoad = function (event) {
        // ...
    }
```

Note: "sb" is just the prefix I use for my custom directives.

Comment: Thanks Sam, this works like a charm, I think I'll leave the sb prefix to give you credit.

Comment: Thumbs up for a scale-able solution that works well without jqLite (which was removed from Angular 2)

Answer (score 31):

Ok, jqLite' [`bind`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) method doing well its job. It goes like this:

We are adding directive' name as attribute in our `img` tag . In my case  , after loading and depending on its dimensions , image have to change its class name from "horizontal" to "vertical"  , so directive's name will be "orientable" :

```
<img ng-src="image_path.jpg" class="horizontal" orientable />
```

And then we are creating simple directive like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('orientable', function () {       
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   

            element.bind("load" , function(e){ 

                // success, "onload" catched
                // now we can do specific stuff:

                if(this.naturalHeight > this.naturalWidth){
                    this.className = "vertical";
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Example (explicit graphics!): http://jsfiddle.net/5nZYZ/63/

Answer (score 7):

AngularJS [V1.7.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#173-eventful-proposal-2018-08-03) Added the `ng-on-xxx` directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <img ng-on-load="onImgLoad($event)">
</div>
```

AngularJS provides specific directives for many events, such as `ngClick`, so in most cases it is not necessary to use `ngOn`. However, AngularJS does not support all events  and new events might be introduced in later DOM standards.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-on Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOn).