# Angular ng-repeat "done event"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use "ng-repeat" in angular to render an array of images. for example:

```
<div ng-cloak class="thumbs" ng-hide="uploadDisplay" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
    <img ng-src="{{photo.url}}" ng-title="{{photo.description}}"/>
</div>
```

but how can i know all the images have finish rendered. Then i can call a third party plugin with:

```
$('.thumbs a').touchTouch();
```

Some kinds of plugins like touchTouch, need to initial the static Dom of images in page, but not allowed for dynamic dom.
How can i use this kind of plugin here? is there function like onLoad in Angular that will be called after Dom finish render?

Comment: Use directive approach, it is easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547917/angularjs-image-onload-event

Comment: you need to add a directive and handle that in your module. See example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event

Comment: Don't `$('.thumbs a').touchTouch();`. Use an angular-based solution. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/161278