# Data not appearing in template via img.onload()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

EDIT: the following example doesn't do any useful work. It's just to illustrate my problem setting template variables from within `img.onload`. The actual image manipulation doesn't matter.

So I'm trying to convert an image to base64 as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript) answer and then adapt it for use in an angular project.

I can get the image encoded to base64, but then I can't get that data to appear in a template.

In my controller, I have the following:

```
vm.showInTemplate = "cluck";
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';
img.onload = function(){
    // logic removed for simplicity
    vm.showInTemplate= "moooo";
};
```

Then in the view, I have (for now):

```
{{ vm.showInTemplate }}
```

I know from Chrome console that `vm.showInTemplate` is available in `img.onload()` and I know that it is being set to `"moooo"`, but in the template view, the value remains `"cluck"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since .onload is async, I guess you need to call an angular method to refresh the template. Sometime it's $scope.$apply() for $scope.property. It would help to know what "vm" is.

Comment: Yep. This is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try jQuery? bind know load image, iframe and other object. Look a example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img#example').bind('load', function() { 
  console.log('load done'); 
 });
 $('button#load').click(function() { 
  $('img#example').attr('src','http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="example" src="">
<button id="load">EXAMPLE</button>
```

Comment: I'm not just looking to display the image. It has to be available to the angular template.

Comment: i see... check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547917/angularjs-image-onload-event

Answer (score 0):

Answer was obvious, thanks to progysm. Posting it here to save future generations a little time:

```
var url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';
var img = new Image();
vm.showInTemplate= 'oink';
img.src = url;
img.onload = function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        vm.showInTemplate = "mooo";
    });
};
```

The controller-as syntax confused me for a moment, but there's no reason not to use good ol' `$scope` here.