# img load event not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to following directive that I am trying to set an onload listener for the img tag.  Inside that link function I programmatically generate the img src.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('imgTest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}"></img>',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.on('load', function() {
        console.log('image loaded');
      });

      scope.imgSrc = "someurl?token=" + getAccessToken();  
    }
  };
});
```

However the onload function is not firing.  Please go easy, I am sure I am doing something really stupid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"elem" is not the image. If you use your directive like the following,

```
<div img-test />
```

elem is the "div" instead of the image

Answer (score 0):

`elem.on('load')` is a jQuery-style event listener. It doesn't look like you have a jQuery object as `elem` there - it came straight from Angular. So try:

```
$(elem).on('load', function () {})
```

or

```
elem.addEventListener('load', function() {});
```

Comment: Thanks @Harangue.  Still not getting the load event.  My image is indeed loading as I can see it on the page.

Comment: @lostintranslation I'm also pretty sure you're supposed to set "src" before the load listener. Not sure if that'll make a difference.

Comment: always thought it was best practice to setup the listener before triggering the event that might fire the listener.  Either way though, load even is still not firing.

Comment: @lostintranslation Hmm I guess my only other suspicion is that it's a weird behavior of template directives. Is there any way you can switch to an attribute-based directive, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/26781900/1008741