# trigger radio button when page loaded in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, radio-button

With **angularjs** I have the following `execute()` function,it print the value of checked `radio button` and it works fine,but I need to execute this function when page loaded just if one `radio button` has checked.

-in this case when page loaded it should print 3 in console

-if `vm.value=null` function shouldn't execute

I need to trigger function only if one radio button has checked

```
vm.value="3";

vm.execute=function(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

Html code

```
<input type="radio" ng-change=vm.execute(1) value="1" ng-model="vm.value">
<input type="radio" ng-change=vm.execute(2) value="2" ng-model="vm.value">
<input type="radio" ng-change=vm.execute(3) value="3" ng-model="vm.value">
<input type="radio" ng-change=vm.execute(4) value="4" ng-model="vm.value">
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, so I'll offer two ways: You may execute function in controller by yourself by just calling it: `vm.execute(vm.value)`, so when the controller is loaded, it would be executed. Or you may create a directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547917/

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your controller

```
if(!angular.equals(vm.value, null)){
   vm.execute(vm.value)
}
```