# How to have loader spinner persist until entire view content has loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this in my controller right now, but it only shows the spinner for a second and then goes away, even though the content is still clearly loading

```
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(event, data) {
      $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
    });
});


$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterEnter", function(event, data) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: you mean the content of the things that you request through `$http`? The content that ionic is referring to is `viewContent` of angular, I think you mix up the two.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I do not request anything, just the images I use are very large and take a few seconds (maybe 2-3 secs) to load

Comment: the [`ionicView`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) refers to the `viewContent` of angular, and not on the onload of image being load. Angular (or Ionic for that matter) are yet to support this. What you could do is write a directive to handle the image onload event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547917/angularjs-image-onload-event

Comment: Awesome...I'll take a look. Thanks :)