# Convert jQuery element to a regular dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery

A regular dom element is such as:

`document.getElementById('a')`

or

`document.createElement('div')`

But jQuery returns elements in another format, so for instance I'd like to convert what is returned by `$('#a')` to the same result as what is returned by `document.getElementById('a')`

Is this possible using jQuery?

thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify you question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can reference the DOM element with `.get(0)` or `[0]`, eg `$('#foo')[0]` assuming there is just one.

Answer (score 9):

That is what **[get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)** method was made for by JQuery team, consider:

```
var elem = $('#a')[0];
```

Or

```
var elem1 = $('#a').get(0);
var elem2 = document.getElementById('a');
alert(elem1 === elem2);
```

or longer version:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>   
<a id='a'></a>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>

    var elem1 = $('#a').get(0);
    var elem2 = document.getElementById('a');
    alert(elem1 === elem2);

  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should really be the selected answer. When you used the === (relational operator), it really drove it home for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#a')[0]
```

// oops my answer is too short