# Using list.js sort and search not working

Tags: javascript, listjs

This is my first time using list.js and for some reason it is not working.

Here is a live example.
http://hartslogmuseum.com/bookhjr10/test.php
here is what its supposed to do 
http://listjs.com/examples

And here is my code. I want to search only the name.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="catalog">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort Name
  </button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="cat">
    Sort Category
  </button>
 <h2> Catalog </h2>
<table class="list table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
<td> <h2 class="name">Item Name</h2> </td>
<td><h2 class="cat">Item Category</h2></td>
<td> <h2>Thumbnail</h2></td>
<td> <h2 class="descr">Item Desc</h2> </td>
<td> <h2 class="time">Time Frame</h2> </td>
<td> <h2 class="donor">Donor</h2> </td>


</tr>
$resultSet = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM bookhjr10_items");

While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet))
{
$i=0;   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class=\"name\">".$row['name']. "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"cat\">".$row['category']. "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"fullimage.php?id=".$row['id']."\" data-lightbox=\pic\"><img src=\"image.php?id=".$row['id']."\" alt=\"thumb-1\" /></a></td>";
echo "<td class=\"descr\">". $row['descr'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"time\">". $row['time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class=\"donor\">". $row['donor'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}

?>
</table>
</div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name' ]
};

var hackerList = new List('catalog', options);
</script>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? Do you get any error in the console? *edit:* If you look at the console, you get an bunch of these errors: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. Some of your scripts (e.g. jQuery) are not found.

Comment: I've tried changing the class names. I'm not getting any errors. When I type in the search box everything goes away. That's what it should do and only show what you type but for some reason it isn't working like that.
Yeah those were things I didn't need. I took them out.

Comment: All I need is the http://listjs.com/overview/download list.ls correct? I don't need to do anything else?

Answer (score 17):

You probably forgot one of the minimal requirements.

These seem the minimal requirements:

1. Indicate the table's parent element ID when calling `list.js`
2. The table's `tbody` must have the class `list`
3. If the table already has items (most cases I would assume), the options' valueNames parameter is mandatory. These values are the class name of the columns you want to sort (class name defined in EACH `td`, not on the `th` - although you can also add it to the `th`).
4. The table headers used for sorting must have a class of name `sort`
5. The table headers used for sorting must have a attribute `data-sort` with a value matching the name of the column's class name to be sorted

Here are a couple of list.js codepen examples using tables (this is from http://listjs.com/examples/add-get-remove):

- http://codepen.io/javve/pen/cLdfw
- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IvlsJ

Minimal code example:

see also on http://jsfiddle.net/d7fJs/

```
<!-- for a table with a parent div of id "my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper", -->
<!-- and columns of class names "gender", "age" & "city" -->

<div id="my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="gender">Gender</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="age">Age</th>
            <th class="sort" data-sort="city">City</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="list">
            <tr>
                <td class="gender">male</td>
                <td class="age">18</td>
                <td class="city">Berlin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gender">female</td>
                <td class="age">46</td>
                <td class="city">Reykjavik</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gender">female</td>
                <td class="age">20</td>
                <td class="city">Lisboa</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- and so on ...-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'gender', 'age', 'city' ]
    };
    var contactList = new List('my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper', options);
</script>
```

**Note:** if the sorting behaves strangely - ie. the sorting is incorrect - it might be because you are missing one of the basic requirements. If you struggle, do a jsfiddle & ask your question on stackoverflow with a link to it.

---

If you want to avoid using this ID in the wrapping element, and use a custom selector instead, you can replace:

```
var contactList = new List('my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper', options);
```

By this:

```
var wrapperElement = $('.my .custom .selector');
var contactList = new List(wrapperElement[0], options);
```

see:

- [Convert jQuery element to a regular dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441535/can-jquery-change-a-jquery-element-to-a-normal-dom-element)
- https://github.com/javve/list.js/issues/247#issuecomment-45215836

---

If you want to detect change events triggered by `List.js` & act accordingly (here we update row class names accordingly)

```
contactList.on("updated", function(){
    $('#my-cool-sortable-table-wrapper tr').removeClass('odd').filter(':visible:odd').addClass("odd");
})
```

`List.js` handles different event types. See full list at the bottom of [this page http://listjs.com/docs/list-api](http://listjs.com/docs/list-api)

---

Official documentation http://listjs.com/docs/options

Comment: For searching/filtering, one other (seemingly undocumented) requirement appears to be that the search <input> has to be in the div specified when calling the List constructor (as well as have the class "search"). I realize OP was just asking about sorting, but your answer is more generally applicable and better for getting oriented with List.js than the official documentation, so wanted to make a note here for others.

Answer (score 2):

When using list.js with tables you should add `class="list"` to a `<tbody>` tag instead of the `<table>` tag.

So in your code change this part:

```
<table class="list table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
```

to

```
<table class="table-bordered table-striped">
<tbody class="list">
<tr>
```

And don't forget to add a `</tbody>`.

Answer (score -3):

```
***Add php tag before you start php code in an html content.***
//You can refer to below example:
<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="catalog">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort Name
  </button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="cat">
    Sort Category
  </button>
 <h2> Catalog </h2>
<table class="list table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
<td> <h2 class="name">Name</h2> </td>
</tr>
<?php   
$sql="SELECT * FROM country";
$resultSet = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet))
{?>
<tbody >
<tr><td class="name">
<?php 
$i=0;   
echo $row['cn_name'];
$i++;
}?>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
      </div>
//Javascript
<script src="http://listjs.com/no-cdn/list.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name' ]//you can specify more columns by adding ,
};

var hackerList = new List('catalog', options);
</script>
```