# list.js javascript library not working

Tags: html, sorting, javascript

I am looking forward to use the [list.js by Jonny](http://listjs.com/). Here, in its examples, I am trying to use the same list code as given [here](http://listjs.com/examples). I copied the HTML,CSS and JS part in my code file. Also, I downloaded and saved the `list.js` given and pasted it in the same directory as my code file. I am using WAMP and when I open the page, the search function does not work as it works online. The table does not update dynamically and even it doesn't update when I click `sort by name` button.

Can someone please tell what might be the problem? Thanks :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="list.js"></script><meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Existing list</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
</script>
<style>
.list {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px 0 0;
}
.list > li {
  display:block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.avatar {
  max-width: 150px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0 0 0.3rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-weight:bold;
}
p {
  margin:0;
}

input {
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:7px 14px;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
input:focus {
  outline:none;
  border-color:#aaa;
}
.sort {
  padding:8px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #28a8e0;
  height:30px;
}
.sort:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:#1b8aba;
}
.sort:focus {
  outline:none;
}
.sort:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  top:-10px;
  right:-5px;
}
.sort.asc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  top:13px;
  right:-5px;
}
.sort.desc:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  top:-10px;
  right:-5px;
}
</style>
  <div id="users">
    <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
    <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
      Sort by name
    </button>

    <ul class="list">
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
        <p class="born">1986</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Jonas Arnklint</h3>
        <p class="born">1985</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Martina Elm</h3>
        <p class="born">1986</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</h3>
        <p class="born">1983</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console, or performed any other basic debugging tasks at all?

Comment: Sure sounds like the .js file you are using isn't being loaded.  Two possibilities: it's in the wrong directory, in which case the "network" tab of your developer tools will tell you where it's expected.  Or, your html page isn't ever referring to the .js file in the first place, and you need to refer to it in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I am using dreamweaver and it is not showing any errors. I am editing the question to include my whole code too.. :)

Comment: it is in the same directory as that of the above page. And BTW, I have the above page named as temp.php! Will the .php extension affect the behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Javascript`:

```
  <script>
    var options = {
      valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
    };

    var userList = new List('users', options);
  </script>
```

Needs to be placed underneath the `HTML` (before the closing body tag), because the `script` needs to run after the `html`. Currently you have the `script` above the `html` - so it doesn't know that the markup exists yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked! I am a newbie in web dev, so didn't know these subtle points :) Thanks Again!

Comment: read more regarding minimal requirements http://stackoverflow.com/a/23078200/759452