# get naturalWidth of image via its src

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

If i had an image with a url such as `img/160x180.jpg` how using this alone in jquery/javascript can i get the width and height of it. i have tried

```
alert($('<img src="img/160x180.jpg"/>').naturalWidth)
```

in the example below it returns undefined.

### http://jsfiddle.net/D7dx6/

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832907/is-there-any-way-to-read-out-the-naturalwidth-of-an-image-with-jquery

Comment: not at all... the link you have given specififes $(this).naturalHeight; leaving me assuming the image is already existant in the document wheras mine isn't...!

Comment: There are others answers that do not assume the image is in the document

Comment: so there are solutions for my problem meaning it's not a duplicate...

Comment: Take a look at Fyodor Kupolov's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Updated:](http://jsfiddle.net/D7dx6/1/)

```
alert($('<img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif"/>')[0].width);
```

*edit* — that doesn't really make sense; it needs to be in an event handler:

```
$('<img/>', {
  'load': function() { alert(this.width); },
  'src': 'http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif'
});
```

That code, it should be noted, *might* have problems on IE because it sometimes drops the ball if the "src" is set and the image is found in cache *before* the "load" handler is established. In that case, you can do this:

```
$('<img/>', { 'load': function() { alert(this.width); } }).prop('src', 'http://...');
```

There's no "naturalWidth" property.

Though it's pretty much irrelevant overhead in this case, you can do this without jQuery like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(img.width);
};
img.src = "http://placekitten.com/300/400";
```

Now one thing to watch out for is that if you're looking at actual *page* elements (that is, `<img>` tags on the page), they might have "width" attributes that override the true size. Fetching the image again will generally pull it out of cache, though there's some potential pain there for huge images on mobile devices.

(*edit* — Graham points out that there *is* a "naturalWidth", but it's not well-supported at this time.)

Comment: I guessed there wasn't a naturalWidth I just didn't have another way of asking for what i needed..and thankyou this is brilliant :)

Comment: quick question why does it sometimes return 0 ?

Comment: uhh ... I don't know; does it?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry - that needs to be in an "onload" handler, as in my example. Durrr.

Answer (score 2):

`naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` aren't well supported yet: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement.

The pure-JavaScript way to determine the original dimensions of an image, whether or not it currently exists in the DOM, is to use the `Image` object.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'path/to/img.jpg';
// you'll probably want to use setTimeout to wait until the imh.complete is true
console.log(img.width);
```